# VS code GLSL lint creating shader files when saving

Tags: visual-studio-code, glsl, shader, editor

I am using the VS coide extension GLSL lint to help me keep my shader code clean and I am noticing that if I save I get a spir-v binary of the shader I am saving on my root directory.

e.g.

[image]

Can I disable that feature or at least specify a directory to which to poutput the file?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Running into the same problem.

Comment: No, I think the problem went away after resetting my OS.